# Filter by one MDX dimension but display another

Tags: mdx

I'm trying to write an MDX query that limits the results returned by one dimension of my cube but displays the aggregate from another, does anyone know if this is possible?

What I effectively want to execute is:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY
Filter([Index].[Index].Members, [Imnt Ctry].[ImntCtry].CurrentMember.Name<>"GB")
ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[T.SUM], [Measures].[B.SUM], [Measures].[L.SUM], [Measures].[SBL.SUM], [Measures].[P.SUM], [Measures].[R.SUM], [Measures].[Coll.SUM], [Measures].[Long.SUM], [Measures].[Short.SUM], [Measures].[Firm.SUM], [Measures].[Net.SUM], [Measures].[PTH.SUM]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [PositionsCube]
```

This executes but returns nothing, I can alternatively execute:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY
Crossjoin([Index].[Index].Members, Filter([Imnt Ctry].[ImntCtry].Members, [Imnt Ctry].[ImntCtry].CurrentMember.Name<>"GB"))
ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[T.SUM], [Measures].[B.SUM], [Measures].[L.SUM], [Measures].[SBL.SUM], [Measures].[P.SUM], [Measures].[R.SUM], [Measures].[Coll.SUM], [Measures].[Long.SUM], [Measures].[Short.SUM], [Measures].[Firm.SUM], [Measures].[Net.SUM], [Measures].[PTH.SUM]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [PositionsCube]
```

which gives me the correct result set, but is now aggregating by Index > Imnt Ctry where I just want Index.

Additionally I have tried declaring a set and using an Intersection, but the intersection has to declare the same dimensions as the set else doesn't parse so is no more use.

It seems this would be a logical operation to want to perform, but I just can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Slice Section.

```
WITH  
Set [FilterImnt] As (Filter([Imnt Ctry].[ImntCtry].Members, [Imnt Ctry].[ImntCtry].CurrentMember.Name<>"GB"))
SELECT
NON EMPTY
{[Index].[Index].Members} 
ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[T.SUM], [Measures].[B.SUM], [Measures].[L.SUM], [Measures].[SBL.SUM], [Measures].[P.SUM], [Measures].[R.SUM], [Measures].[Coll.SUM], [Measures].[Long.SUM], [Measures].[Short.SUM], [Measures].[Firm.SUM], [Measures].[Net.SUM], [Measures].[PTH.SUM]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [PositionsCube]
Where ({[FilterImnt]})
```